# Where to edit page on WP

Tags: html, wordpress, locate

I took over a website about 6months ago and am having a bit of difficulty finding WHERE items are defined at times.

I am trying to edit
http://www.mercurymosaics.com/mosaic-classes/

On the right there is a section that says:
"View Calendar
Beginner and Advanced Classes"

I want it to say "View Calendar
Beginner Classes"

but can seem to FIND this content to edit. Any help?

Comment: should probably re-title this, not really a fancybox question.

Comment: how not? It's content within the fancy box that I want to edit.

Comment: the fancybox is the div that pops up "over" the website when you click on the "View Calendar" box.  The words "view calendar" and "beginner and advanced classes" are part of the main page, not the fancy box.

Comment: See, that's what I thought myself - fellow coworker said otherwise. Hmm. Okay - retitle. Am looking for the HTML on it then. Cant seem to find for the life of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the boxes are defined in their own area which was linked in the main page above. so I had to sort through a few "see this one" "see this other one" but found it.

Answer (score 0):

search for the following html in your files:

```
<h3>View Calendar</h3>
```

as that is what that section will look like in code. Just underneath that line you will find the verbiage you want to edit.

Comment: (Am on WP) I cant seem to find the content. I can edit the related PHP or CSS files, but can't find this item. Any suggestions? you say "edit html" but I cant find WHAT/Where this is ...

Comment: WP meaning word press?  Thats a different beast, the person who created it could be using a plug-in (or whatever WP calls it) to render the right hand bar.  You will have to find how to edit that before you will find the text you are looking for.  Sorry I don't do word press, so thats about all the help i can give you.

Comment: Yes, wordpress. I wouldn't have such a time if it weren't haha. New to WP - this cursed thing can be a beast at times.

Comment: Yes, i break out the crosses and garlic when someone whispers its name... ughghhg.. i just got the shivers